# Closest ancestor matching selector using native DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, standards, w3c, dom-traversal

Is anybody working on a [jQuery.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) equivalent in the DOM api?

Looks like the [Selectors Level 2 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#matches) adds `matches()` equivalent to [jQuery.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/), so native closest should be much easier to write.  Has adding `closest()` to Selectors come up?

Comment: It "should be easier" only if all browsers implement the method—they don't. :-( So a longhand method must be written anyway, I guess with feature detection for a `macthes` fork. It wouldn't be hard, but likely a little slow.

Comment: Yeah, [modernizer has an example](http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixeddom) of falling back to vendor prefixed `matchesSelector`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the element.closest() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Implementing such function with Element.matches() seems not optimal in terms of performance, cause apparently matches() will make a call to querySelectorAll() every time you test a parent, while only one call is sufficient for the job.

Here's a polyfill for closest() on MDN. Note a single call to querySelectorAll()

```
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = 
  function(s) {
      var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
          i,
          el = this;
      do {
          i = matches.length;
          while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
      } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
      return el;
  };
}
```

But bear in mind that function implemented like this will not work properly on unattached tree (detached from document.documentElement root)

```
//Element.prototype.closestTest = function(s){...as seen above...};

var detachedRoot = document.createElement("footer");
var child = detachedRoot.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
detachedRoot.parentElement; //null

child.closestTest("footer"); //null

document.documentElement.append(detachedRoot);
child.closestTest("footer"); //<footer>
```

Though closest() that is implemented in Firefox 51.0.1 seems to work fine with detached tree

```
document.documentElement.removeChild(detachedRoot);
child.closestTest("footer"); //null
child.closest("footer"); //<footer>
```

Comment: Seems to no longer be "experimental" according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 36):

Building off of Alnitak's answer. Here's the working current implementation with `matchesSelector` which is now `matches` in the DOM spec.

```
// get nearest parent element matching selector
function closest(el, selector) {
    var matchesSelector = el.matches || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector;

    while (el) {
        if (matchesSelector.call(el, selector)) {
            break;
        }
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return el;
}
```

Browser support is great: http://caniuse.com/matchesselector

Comment: I'm torn.  Thanks for the implementation, but does it mean native closest isn't coming?

Comment: Why `.bind(ctx)(arg)` rather than `.call(ctx, arg)` ?  The former creates a new execution context, the latter doesn't.

Comment: `call(elem, selector)` has better performance than `bind(elem)(selector)`, benchmark http://jsperf.com/native-vs-jquery-closest. Still simple `.parentNode.parentNode` method is highly faster.

Comment: Why return false, not null?

Comment: Good call. Thanks yall!

Answer (score 14):

Seems like Chrome 40 will bring a native `element.closest()` method (http://blog.chromium.org/2014/12/chrome-40-beta-powerful-offline-and.html) specified here: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest

Comment: `element.closest` has landed in Chrome 41, not 40 (see https://crbug.com/422731#c7). And it has also landed in [Firefox 35](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35)

Comment: You can also use a polyfill to use this function on older browsers, for example https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it ought to be pretty easy, given the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) function, although that's not widely supported yet:

```
function closest(elem, selector) {
    while (elem) {
        if (elem.matches(selector)) {
            return elem;
        } else {
            elem = elem.parentElement;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The trouble is, the `matches` function isn't properly supported.  As it's still a relatively new API it's available as `webkitMatchesSelector` in Chrome and Safari, and `mozMatchesSelector` in Firefox.

Comment: Yep, with `*MatchesSelector`, whipping up a closest using only native DOM gets easy.  I'm more curious if there's any momentum behind adding `element.closest(selector)` as a native method of elements.

Comment: @hurrymaplelad you'd probably have to join W3C and suggest it.  I suspect they wouldn't bother though, given how easy it is to implement (per the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Using element.closest() we can find Closest ancestor matching selector. This method takes selectors list as parameter and returns the closest ancestor. As per Rob's Comment this API will be available from chrome 41 and FF 35.

As explained in whatwg specs https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest

Example: The below HTML will show alert message "true"

```
<html>
    <body>
        <foo>
            <bar>
                <a id="a">
                    <b id="b">
                        <c id="c"></c>
                    </b>
                </a>
            </bar>
         </foo>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById('a');
        var b = document.getElementById('b');
        var c = document.getElementById('c');
        alert(c.closest("a, b")==b);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little recursion will do the trick.

```
// get nearest parent element matching selector
var closest = (function() {
    var matchesSelector = el.matches || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector;

    return function closest(el, selector) {
        return !el ? null :
        matchesSelector.call(el, selector) ? el : closest(el.parentElement, selector);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Or just `return element.tagName === 'HTML' ? null : element.matches(selector) ? element : closest(element.parentNode, selector);` ;)