# Unable to select and change class of UL submenu item

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of update some jQuery code to be in plain JS.  Currently the code is using jQuery closest method to select the closest UL.  I need help in finding the right approach to selecting the closest UL using javascript.

Here is a sample of the HTML code:

```
<ul class ="m_nav_tier m_nav_tier1">
    <li data-nav-tier="1">
        <a class="m_drop" href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul class="m_nav_tier m_nav_tier2">
             <li>One</li>
             <li>Two</li>
             <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to do is change the class of `<ul class="m_nav_tier m_nav_tier2">` when user clicks on Link 1

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var mdrop = document.getElementsByClassName('m_drop');

for (i = 9; i < mdrop.length; i++) {
  //Forward
  mdrop[i].onclick = function () {

  //make tier 1 inactive
  var tier1 = document.getElementsByClassName('m_nav_tier1')[1];
  tier1.className += " inactive";

  //find closest UL and make it active
  document.querySelector('ul .m_nav_tier2')[9].className += " active";
};
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/cg7w93Lq/1/)
*UPDATE:
 I was able to change the class with the following code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('m_nav_tier2')[9].className += " active";
```

But the problem is I have to set the array a value.  I tried placing [i] but that didn't work.  How can I up update the class depending on which LI was selected?

Comment: [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/cg7w93Lq/1/)

Comment: Check this, this could help your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329167/closest-ancestor-matching-selector-using-native-dom

Comment: What's the `mdrop` -variable? The fiddle you provided crashes right at the beginning since it's not defined.

Comment: m_drop is a css transition on the LI elements

Answer (score 0):

from what i am aware your class its base on to the .css and you can do a copy and change from 1 to 2 and what function it has 
and i dont wright .js but i cant see you telling JavaScript where to colect this function ('m_nav_tier1') to be able to convert to  this 
 document.querySelector('ul .m_nav_tier2')[9].className += " active";