# getSelection().focusNode inside a specific id doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code to bold/unbold scripts via Window.getSelection()
I got it from this answer: [Bold/unbold selected text using Window.getSelection()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63365847/14592575)

It really works without problems .
But when I looked for another code to make the selection inside a div specified with id
I found this answer :
[How to getSelection() within a specific div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38758990/14592575)
When I try to combine the first answer with the second answer
I found it doing bold and not unbold
My Code :

```js
function addBold(){

/*
answer 1 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364212/bold-unbold-selected-text-using-window-getselection

answer 2 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758713/how-to-getselection-within-a-specific-div


*/




// answer 2 
if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id != "editor") return;
// end answer 2 



// answer 1 
  const selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  
  let selectedParent = selection.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;
  

  let mainParent = selectedParent;
  
  if(selectedParent.closest("b"))
  {
  //Unbold
    var text = document.createTextNode(selectedParent.textContent);
    mainParent = selectedParent.parentElement;
    mainParent.insertBefore(text, selectedParent);
    mainParent.removeChild(selectedParent);
    mainParent.normalize();
  }
  else
  {
    const span = document.createElement("b");
    span.appendChild(selection.extractContents());
    selection.insertNode(span);
    mainParent.normalize();
  }
  
  //selection is set to body after clicking button for some reason
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript
  if (window.getSelection) {
    if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
      window.getSelection().empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
    document.selection.empty();
  }

// end answer 1



};
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">

You are the programmers of the future 

</div>


<button onclick="addBold()">Bold</button>
```

Like I said when you combined the two an
swers
Makes bold and ignores unbold

If you delete the first line of the validation condition,
if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id
It will work successfully  Bold/Unbold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id
When creating bold

The parent element of the text is obtained
and find it
**Text**
Therefore, he did not reach the main father element who kissed him
So replace the first line with this line and it works successfully
Replace

window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id != "editor"

To

window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.closest("#editor").id != "editor"