# Select elements whose specific descendants' HTML contains a specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select all `div` which has a `cite` descendant and that `cite` descendant's HTML contains some `text`. I have tried:

```
$('div')
  .filter('cite')
    .filter(function() {
              return $(this).html().match('text');
    })
```

and this:

```
$('div')
  .filter('div cite')
    .filter(function() {
              return $(this).html().match('text');
    })
```

but it is not working. What is missing here?

That is, I want to select the 3rd `div` in the following HTML.

HTML:

```
<div id="abcd">text1 text2</div>
<div id="abccd">text1 text2</div>
<div id="abcccd">
  <cite><b>text1</b>text2</cite>
</div>
<div id="abd">text1 text2</div>
```

EDIT:
The thing I want to select is **not** `$('div cite')`. I want to select `$('div')`, where `div`s have a `cite` descendant and that `cite` descendant's contents contain some text.

Comment: please share html code as well

Comment: You want all the texts within cite?

Comment: @Sky Yes. I want to compare some text with the contents of the `cite` and select accordingly.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The 3rd `div` is what I want to select.

Comment: @Utku You can try filter the div object, then check the text of cite under it. I'm using phone typing, so it's great if suggestion helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
$("div").has("cite:contains('text')");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `:contains()` selector:

```
$("div").find("cite:contains('text')").closest("div");
```

Thanks to @JonSG:

> The OP. has asked in the comments of a different answer how this might
>   be done with just filter() without walking back up the tree with
>   closest() or parent(). I'm not keen on this answer, but you might do:

```
var target = $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find("cite:contains('text')").length !== 0;
});

$(target).css("background-color", "coral");
```

Or:

```
var target = $("div").filter(function() {
  return /text/.test($(this).find("cite").html());
});

$(target).css("background-color", "tomato");
```

Comment: This selects the `cite` element. I want to select the `div` elements which have a `cite` descendant that contains some `text`.

Comment: This answer is close, but would need a **.closest("div")** or perhaps a **.parent()**

Comment: @Utku, It now selects the `div`.

Comment: @Utku, sure see my answer below that does essentially that.

Comment: @JonSG But it still uses `closest()`. Is it possible to do it using only `filter()`s?

Comment: @Utku Yes but there is no need to use that, jQuery selectors already do that. It would be like using `getElementById` instead of `$('#...')`. Unless you are looking for a native JS solution. For the same functionality of `closest()` in native JS see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329167/closest-ancestor-matching-selector-using-native-dom).

Comment: @Utku, Yes, `$("div cite").filter(":contains('text')").closest("div");`

Comment: @dNitro I meant, starting with `$('div').filter(...)`. Not with `$('div cite').filter(...)`. I.e, not using `closest()` at all.

Comment: Yes, I added a second example to my answer that uses **filter()** without **closest()**.  If @dNitro adds it to his answer as a second example, I will delete my answer as his seem better overall.

Comment: @Utku , Like this: `$("div").filter(function(index) { return /text/.test($(this).find("cite").html());
  });`

Comment: @JonSG, Added, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$("div cite").each(function() {`

```
     ` // $(this).text() get the text of cite`
```

`});`

Comment: *" HTML contains some `text`"*

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
$( "cite" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xONxbZ

Comment: @Utku , this answer will get you all the text array between cite tags ,if cite tags are more than one